Is there any way to prevent the creation of `package_xxx` directory in Uno?
When building the output, Uno creates a package_xxx folder. The docs mention that there is a MSBuild WasmShellOutputPackagePath variable set but I would rather have a constant folder name (eg. AppBundle...) so it can be easily consumed further downstream (Eg. webpack, tscript config paths etc etc).
Is there any way to control this behavior?

You can use dotnet publish feature in your CI to pack the files in the correct destination for your tooling.
Doc: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-publishing-webassembly.html#packaging-your-app-using-the-cli
